# Help with opening a file in C on Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, file

I'm trying to open a simple .rtf file called test in C.  I'm using Xcode.  My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    FILE *filePtr;
    filePtr = fopen("test.rtf", "r");
    if (filePtr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open \"test\"\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        printf("File open successful\n");
        int x;
        /* read one character at a time until EOF is reached */
        while ((x = fgetc(filePtr)) != EOF) {
            printf("%c", x);
        }
    }
    fclose(filePtr);
    return 0;   
}
```

I have the test.rtf file in the same directory as my Xcode.proj directory.  My output is "File open successful", however I do not get anything read from the file.  Am I doing this right?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you see something if you add `putc('\n', filePtr);` before the `return 0;`?  You might not be seeing anything if there is no newline in the file.

Comment: No I do not see anything when I add this before the return 0;

Comment: Hmm. What does `xxd -l 32 test.rtf` from the commandline say?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with that code at all. I tested it (albeit not in Xcode) with a file and the transcript was:

```
pax> echo hello >test.rtf
pax> ./qq.exe
File open successful
hello
```

So the obvious think to ask is what happens when you examine test.rtf? Does it actually have any content? Because, when I do:

```
pax> rm test.rtf ; touch test.rtf
pax> ./qq.exe
File open successful
```

I get the same behaviour you observe.

Also try renaming it to test2.rtf temporarily and make sure you get the error. It's possible it may be opening a different copy of the file than what you think (this often happens in Visual C since the directory the program runs in is not always what developers think at first).

Comment: I changed "test.rtf" in the filePtr = fopen("test.rtf", "r") to "t.rtf" to make sure I get the error printed when the file does not open. The .rtf file I have I just put some random text in there like "hello (newline) does this (newline) work".

Comment: The only thing I can think of now is to test the return value of the `printf()` call!

Comment: What happens when you change 'printf("%c", x);' to 'fprintf(stderr,"%x\n", x);'? If you got the error okay when the file wasn't there, minimise the differences between the output calls - both use stderr, both output something with newlines.

Comment: Same output. File open successful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks right.

As for the lack of output, two possibilities:

- Are you sure the file has some content?  Maybe `ls -l test.rtf` or `dir test.rft`
- Possibly it has some control characters which cause the terminal to which it is written to suppress output.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `test.rtf` to your build directory. If your project is named `MyProject`, move it to `MyProject/build/Debug/`.

Comment: Unlikely to be the cause.  OP says `File open successful` appears.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two things that could cause this problem.  Either there is an error when calling fgetc, or you are getting output that you don't recognize.

fgetc() will return EOF when the end of the file is reached, or an error occurs.  To determine if it's an error, just after your while loop try:

`if (ferror(filePtr) != 0) printf("error: %d.\n", errno);`

A .rtf file is not a plain text file. It likely contains a bunch of formatting information. You are expecting to see "Hello . . . ".  but what you may actually see is something like:

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf250
>   {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
>   {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
>   \margl1440\margr1440\vieww9000\viewh8400\viewkind0
>   \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040
>   \f0\fs24 \cf0 Hello . . .

And you are just assuming that is GDB output, not your program's output.

Comment: what is GDB?  So I tried creating a new .txt file instead and I keep getting "Can't open test" even though the file is in the same place as the old .rtf file was.  I tried a few different names and put the file in the debug folder along with trying it in the same folder as my Xcode.proj, but this doesn't seem to work either.  Any other things to try out? Thanks.

Comment: GDB is the GNU debugger.  Xcode uses GDB when running a Debug build of a program.  Most of the output you see in Xcode's console is GDB output.  

Did you change the file name to test.txt (or whatever you named the .txt file) in your code?

Comment: Yes.  I created a new text (.txt) file and for some reason it wouldn't open my file and would continue outputting "Cant' open file".

Comment: The next step is to find out why it can't open the file.  fopen should set errno on an error, so output errno.  Change the line 'fprintf(stderr, "Can't open \"test\"\n");' to 'fprintf(stderr, "Can't open \"test\": %d.\n", errno);'.  Then look up what the error number means to find out what needs to be fixed.  

By the way, errno.h must be included to use errno.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your recent comments, I think you have an empty file `test.rtf` in the directory your program is run in, and your real `test.rtf` file is in some other directory.  Maybe your `fopen()` call at some point was `fopen("test.rtf", "w");` instead of `fopen("test.rtf", "r");`, and you later modified it.

To see the directory your program is running in, add the following to your program after the `FILE *filePtr;` line:

```
char pwd[512];
if (getcwd(pwd, sizeof pwd) != -1)
    printf("In directory %s\n", pwd);
else
    fprintf(stderr, "Need bigger buffer, change '512' above\n");
```

Then, you can open a terminal, do `cd <directory>`, and test for yourself if the file you want is the file your program is opening.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this file to be plain text, not rich text. Rich text has a lot of formatting encoded into the file.